# Rails Error: ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, cookiestore

I saw there are multiple posts on this topic on stack overflow but cant apply them.

I got a rails error in my appliciation which I dont' understand: "ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow" (title of error in sentry.io)

I am not using Cookies at all in my app - at least not custom - but I think:

1. devise, an authentication gem I am using, is using cookies. How this can generate an overflow is unclear to me
2. wkhtml, I read on stackoverflow this tool is using Cookies somehow but no clue. But generally I am using it to generate PDFs

Since a customer must have generated this error I have no clue how to reproduce it, which would be kind of useful to figure out what is going on.

Plase provide exceutable instructions how to reproduce and/or to solve this issue.

**Stack trace from sentry.io (as requested in comments):**

**I CANT SEE ANYTHING THERE HENCE I DIDNT POST IT**

```
ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow

actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb in commit at line 637
actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb in []= at line 472
actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb in set_cookie at line 110
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb in commit_session at line 403
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb in context at line 268
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb in call at line 260
actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb in call at line 648
actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb in block in call at line 27
activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb in run_callbacks at line 101
actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb in call at line 26
actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb in call at line 18
actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb in call at line 32
actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb in call at line 33
railties (6.0.3.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb in call_app at line 37
railties (6.0.3.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb in block in call at line 26
activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb in block in tagged at line 80
activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb in tagged at line 28
activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb in tagged at line 80
railties (6.0.3.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb in call at line 26
actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb in call at line 81
actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb in call at line 27
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb in call at line 24
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb in call at line 22
activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb in call at line 29
actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb in call at line 14
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb in call at line 110
actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb in call at line 76
sentry-ruby-core (4.3.2) lib/sentry/rack/capture_exceptions.rb in block in call at line 23
sentry-ruby-core (4.3.2) lib/sentry/hub.rb in with_scope at line 52
sentry-ruby-core (4.3.2) lib/sentry-ruby.rb in with_scope at line 147
sentry-ruby-core (4.3.2) lib/sentry/rack/capture_exceptions.rb in call at line 14
railties (6.0.3.6) lib/rails/engine.rb in call at line 527
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb in process_request at line 107

/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb in accept_and_process_next_request at line 149

/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb in main_loop at line 110

/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb in block (3 levels) in start_threads at line 419

/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb in block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception at line 113
```

Comment: Please share the full error message, include the stacktrace. The stacktrace might tell what code is trying to set the cookie and thereby lead to the gem causing the error.

Comment: @spickermann added the stacktrace above